# css-grid items not aligned at the same level

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this css-grid example...

```css
.toolbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: purple;
}

.tb-left {
  justify-self: start;
  background: green;
}

.tb-right {
  justify-self: end;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="tb-left">TB left</div>
  <div class="tb-right">TB Right</div>
</div>
```

`.tb-left` and `.th-right` are not at the same row level.

How can I made them both be at the same level?

Comment: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` ?

Comment: You explicitly define a **one column grid**, so why on earth would you expect two columns as a result?

Comment: `grid-auto-flow: column;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```css
.toolbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background: purple;
}

.tb-left {
  justify-self: start;
  background: green;
}

.tb-right {
  justify-self: end;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="tb-left">TB left</div>
  <div class="tb-right">TB Right</div>
</div>
```